# Отправка запроса get из js в php и обратно

Tags: php, javascript, get

Как правильно сделать отправку $.get из js в php и обратно
Есть код

```
var test  = 'asd';
$.get("ajax.php", {test:test},
   function(data){
      $('#content').html(data);
   }
);
```

php

```
$test = $_POST['test'];
echo $test;
```

Ответ не приходит

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё очень просто. Вы отправляете GET-запрос, а в PHP-скрипте ожидаете получить POST.

Замените `$_POST['test']` на `$_GET['test']` и всё должно будет заработать.

Comment: @nicolaa, если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте его как решение вашего вопроса - галочкой слева.

Comment: С удовольствием, через 7 минут)Вы можете принять ответ через 7 минут